# Cómo modificar contenido del input "Buscar" de una table bootstrap al presionar un botón, simulando una consulta digitada manualmente en dicho input

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo una tabla (id="tabla_producto") usando bootstrap v4.4.1 definida de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12" id="box_body_div_tabla_producto">
     <table id="tabla_producto" class="table table-bordered table-striped"
                                cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width: 100%;">
     </table>
</div>
```

Dicha tabla se llena correctamente con el contenido de una base de datos MySQL a través de PHP y Javascript.

Quería consultar si con Javascript, luego de cargar inicialmente la tabla, sobre el campo input "Buscar" que aparece luego de mostrarse el contenido de todos los registros leídos de la base de datos, se pueda al presionar diferentes botones, los cuales permitan "modificar" el contenido de dicho campo input "Buscar" como si se hubiese escrito manualmente su contenido, de tal forma que muestre automáticamente un nuevo contenido en la tabla ("tabla_producto") con diferentes registros "seleccionados" dependiendo del botón que se haya presionado.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si, se puede, pero para que recibas ayuda debes poner el código actual del campo Buscar para ver como lo filtras, y al menos un intento de hacer lo que pides con su error correspondiente. Léete [ask] y [example] para aprender a realizar buenas preguntas con el código mínimo necesario para reproducir tu error.  Actualmente no hay error pues no has hecho nada y no se te puede ayudar a corregir nada.

Comment: Entiendo que la generas tu dinámicamente, por lo tanto pon el código correspondiente a eso para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: El programa por el momento no me genera ningún tipo de error, por eso no puedo mostrar un error correspondiente. Lo que quiero es agregar una nueva funcionalidad de que en vez de estar digitando un contenido en el campo input (buscar) que la tabla bootstrap genera en forma automática y que permite al digitar dentro de ese input se logra variar la selección de los registros mostrados, lo que requiero es que ese campo (input) se pueda actualizar (sin digitar dentro de él) a través del evento al presionar un botón.

Comment: En ese sentido, el problema es que no sé cómo identificar el "id" del campo input (buscar) de la tabla bootstrap, ya que la tabla lo genera en forma automática y no sé como acceder a dicho campo para poder modificarlo, ya que como repito no sé cómo identificarlo para poder variar su contenido sin digitarlo manualmente, sino más bien que su contenido varíe "automáticamente" dependiendo del evento del botón que se presione.

Comment: Seguimos a ciegas, la verdad. Dices que se genera automáticamente, pero no dices ni como... con datatables? sea como sea debes poner eso justamente, la forma en como la generas al menos, para que tengamos una referencia y podamos replicarla para ayudarte. Además, si dices que quieres unos botones que pongan valores fijos al campo buscar, donde estan?  como los pones?  Eso tambien debes agregarlo a la pregunta.

Comment: Ademas, no siempre se necesita un **id** para acceder a ese campo **Buscar**, se puede hacer de otras formas, como identificar a uno de sus padres, que podria ser **tabla_producto** y buscarlo por su `type="search"` en caso que lo tenga, y entonces rellenarlo con los botones esos que quieres poner.  Para ver más información sobre ese campo **Buscar** pulsa el botón derecho sobre el y selecciona **Inspeccionar** en su menu contextual y se te abrira el inspector de código justo en esa línea. La copias y la pegas en la pregunta para que podamos verla tambien y poder hacer el filtro

Comment: Gracias Masterguru por tu respuesta..

Comment: He logrado modificar el contenido del campo "input" mediante las siguientes instrucciones:

$("div.dataTables_filter input").val('QUESOS');
$("div.dataTables_filter input").focus();
 
Sin embargo tengo que presionar la tecla <enter> en forma adicional para que el contenido de la table cambie.

Habrá una forma de que me simule el <enter> ?

Comment: quizas con `e = jQuery.Event("keypress"); e.which = 13; $("div.dataTables_filter input").trigger(e);` después del val o del focus

Comment: Lo había probado de la siguiente manera:
$("div.dataTables_filter input").val('QUESOS');
$("div.dataTables_filter input").focus();
var tecla = jQuery.Event("keypress");
tecla.which = 13; 
$("div.dataTables_filter input").trigger(tecla);

Comment: Pero tampoco me funciona. El cursor se queda al final de la palabra 'QUESOS' y tengo que presionar <enter> para que recién reaccione

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para buscar en datatable aprovechamos la función integrada en datatable denominada **[search](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html)** directamente, y la asignamos a una función de este modo:

```
function buscarPalabra(palabra) {
    $('#tabla_producto')
        .DataTable()
        .search(palabra)
        .draw();
}
```

y en los posibles botones lo ponemos así:

```
<button onclick="buscarPalabra('quesos')">
Buscar quesos
</button>
<button onclick="buscarPalabra('mandarinas')">
Buscar mandarinas
</button>
```

Dejo un snippet funcional de muestra:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabla_producto').DataTable();
});

function buscarPalabra(palabra) {
    $('#tabla_producto')
        .DataTable()
        .search(palabra)
        .draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.12.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="buscarPalabra('quesos')">
Buscar quesos
</button>
<button onclick="buscarPalabra('mandarinas')">
Buscar mandarinas
</button>
<table id="tabla_producto" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Comida</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Quesos</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peras</td>
                <td>20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mandarinas</td>
                <td>30</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Comida</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Lamentablemente sigue igual, luego de ejecutarse el alert() el cursor se queda al final de la palabra "QUESOS' y el contenido de la tabla no se modifica a menos que presione un <enter> adicional.

Comment: Pues entonces datatables espera algo más que esa pulsación para ejecutarse correctamente cuando le damos a Buscar... a ver si lo puedo descubrir en su web... segun me parece esta interpretando o bien le evento input o bien el keyup o el change en jquery... mmm... tendre que replicar una tabla de esas para jugar con ella, jolin

Comment: Si es que estabamos reinventando la rueda. Revisa mi respuesta y ejecuta mi snippet a ver si ahora ya estamos.

Comment: Estimado masterguru en realidad eres un MASTER !!!

Comment: Me funcionó muy bien con la rutina que me alcanzaste:

Comment: function buscarPalabra(palabra) {
    $('#tabla_producto')
        .DataTable()
        .search(palabra)
        .draw();
}

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS !!!!!

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro qe te haya funcionado :-)  Los agradecimientos estan bien, pero aqui los agradecimientos se muestran en forma de aceptación de las respuestas. Pulsa en [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo, sino la pregunta quedara pendiente para siempre, gracias.